# NSTimer and Touches event conflict

Tags: iphone, objective-c, touch, nstimer

im trying to execute 2 actions on occurrence of their particular events
one is the animation occurring when the a timer with fixed interval is fired
and other is also a animation occurring when a touch is detected

both r working fine individually but when simultaneously occurring anyone of the animation slows down .its because in the given time unit is performing only one action

for NSTimer im using time interval of 0.01s

How do make this scenario work without slowing down any animation?

Comment: For a start I would reduce the frequency of the animation to something a human being can percieve.

100hz is pretty fast - how long does the animation itself take?

It would asl ohelp to see the code are you using to set up the animations and where in the app you are trigggering them.

Answer (score 1):

NSTimer is not the tool for performing animations. [Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is what you want for almost all animation problems on iPhone. NSTimer is not a real-time timer. It has not guarantees on when it fires. It's an excellent tool for many problems; animation is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

**Touches refusing to respond usually indicates a stressed CPU**. Animating 100 times a second is probably the cause of that.

Answer (score 0):

I would also stop the timer from firing while the touch animation was in progress. You can call [timer invalidate] to stop the timer from firing. Maybe that would do the trick? Time interval of 0.05 would be much more reasonable, though - and may solve the problem entirely! Good luck!